# How send back to the MainActivity the sensor results?

Tags: android, callback, android-sensors

Well, I have a class Sesnsores, where I implement the SensorEventListener and register it. I need to send back to the MainActivity de values of X, Y and Z, 
but what I'm trying doesn't work.

I create this interface in the sensores class:

```
public interface SensorListener {
    void onSensorChanged(float x, float y, float z);
}
```

Then, I create an atribute with this:

```
private SensorListener sListener;
```

In the SensorEventListener, I use the interface to send the results:

```
private SensorEventListener sel = new SensorEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        sListener.onSensorChanged(sensorEvent.values[0], sensorEvent.values[1], sensorEvent.values[2]); ;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

    }
};
```

Obviously, I implement the interface in the MainActivity and use it like this:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(float x, float y, float z) {
    etEjeX.setText(String.valueOf(x));
    etEjeY.setText(String.valueOf(y));
    etEjeZ.setText(String.valueOf(z));
}
```

What am I doing wrong? The application is minimized as soon as I open it and it does not let me do anything.

Comment: Did you put a log or tried to debug the `onSensorChange`? Is it getting called?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I hadn't implemented the onAtatch method and my variable was null.